# Событие input не работает одновременно с событием change на iphone

Tags: javascript, html, iphone

Есть численное поле для ввода, которое участвует в динамической работе калькулятора (то есть по его событию change начинают грузится данные). И есть задача сделать для этого числа разделение по разрядам прямо в процессе ввода (то есть, получается, по событию input). На десктопе, андроиде все работает, однако на iphone, при существовании на инпуте обработчиков для двух событий - input и change, срабатывает только обработчик события input. При отсутствии обработчика события input, обработчик для change корректно отрабатывает.
В чем причина такого странного поведения? Как его исправить? Или, может быть, есть другие способы сделать разделение числа по разрядам на лету?

Comment: Причина такого странного поведения в том что сафаря это "тот же IE, вид сбоку". Просто обрабатывай одно событие `input`, оно вроде при любом ручном изменении значения файрится... зачем тебе еще и `change` в этой задаче?

Comment: @yar85, при change запускаются расчеты, которые могут  занимать до минуты времени. Поэтому обращаться к серверу при каждом input это абсурд)

Comment: Тогда попробуй `blur` использовать вместо `change`. Судя по caniuse, это событие огрызки поддерживают.

Comment: И не в обиду, но ресурсу у которого вебмордочка может фетчить данные до минуты - ничто не поможет :( Юзеры не будут столько ждать. Чтобы не было бегства юзеров, ожидание интерактивности не должно превышать 10 секунд. А в идеале - до 1 секунды (все что больше секунды, должно закрываться индикаторами загрузки или анимациями: это чуть задерживает пользователя, но панацеей не является, конечно... дольше чем на полминуты не удержит даже самая красивая анимация, т.к. повторяемость/однообразие тоже ухудшает UX, хотя и меньше чем задержки).

Comment: @yar85, анимации и индикаторов загрузки на сайте в достатке) Просто данные идут с файла ексель, который весит под 250 МБ ^_^

Comment: Анимации не закрывают проблему: они только слегка растягивают лимит, но не творят чудес. Секунд 15 спиннера при заполнении формы, и средний посетитель сбежал (исключая те случаи, когда остаться на сайте вынуждают обстоятельства... то есть, написанное относится прежде всего к развлекательным и рекламным ресурсам, то есть ко всем тем которые потребности не удовлетворяют, а создают. Понятно, что например внося оплату, юзер будет более терпеливо ждать (по сравнению с любой операцией где его материальный интерес не участвует), и т.д.. Если бэкэнд тормозит, советую кэшировать на клиенте по максимуму